# display error when spanning upvote plugin like stack overflow

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a jQuery up vote plugin. Everything is working fine except the error handling. My up vote plugin is in a foreach loop. like this below

```
  if($RES['counter'] === '1'){
     echo '
             <td>
               <div  data-id='.$id.' class="upvote upvote-serverfault">
                <a style="cursor:pointer;" class="upvote upvote-on" title="This idea is helpful"></a>
                <span class="count">'.$counter.'</span>
                <a class="downvote"></a>
                <span id='.$index.'><span class="votingFeedback"></span>
              </div>
          </td>';  
        }
        else 
            if($RES['counter'] === '-1'){
        echo '
          <td>
            <div  data-id='.$id.' class="upvote upvote-serverfault">
                <a style="cursor:pointer;" class="upvote upvote-down" title="This idea is helpful"></a>
                <span class="count">'.$counter.'</span>
                <a class="downvote downvote-on"></a>
                <span id='.$index.'><span class="votingFeedback"></span>  
            </div>
          </td>';
        }
```

The problem is when the user tries to span my voting system it will throw an error.The error checking is done in my PHP file and It's working but when I tries to dispaly the error on screen instead of showing the message on that particular topic is it shows on all the topic id

[image]

I was trying to make something like stack overflow. If you try to span the up or down vote it will throw and error but it's seems harder then I thought

My ajax call to my php file

```
<script>
var callback = function(data) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'voting.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: { id: data.id, up: data.upvoted, down: data.downvoted, star: data.starred },
        success: function(data) {      
        $(".votingFeedback").html(data);
    }
    });
};
$('.upvote').upvote({callback: callback});

 </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting unrecognized expression because you are replacing your original data variable with the new results from the ajax. from @allcutt answer try changing it to this.

```
var callback = function(data) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'voting.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: { id: data.id, up: data.upvoted, down: data.downvoted, star: data.starred },
        success: function(result) {      
        $("[data-id='" + data.id + "'] .votingFeedback").html(result);
    }
    });
};
$('.upvote').upvote({callback: callback});
```

Comment: it's working but another error Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [data-id='61' .votingFeedback]

Comment: Class should be outside, didn't notice that. probably don't even need it.

Comment: He needs the `.votingFeedback` selector or else it will replace the entire html instead of just the text he wants to show. There also needs to be a space after the brackets because you need to select a child element, not the same element as the one with data-id

Comment: I should of explained, he is better off placing it inside the returned html instead of leaving it blank, that way he could of removed the .votingFeedback selector

Answer (score 3):

When you get a response back from your ajax request you are selecting all voting feedback elements on the page because you are using a class selector. This is updating all the span with the class `votingFeedback`

You need to use a selector that is unique to the element you want to update. You already have a container div with the id. Use that as part of the selector.

`$("[data-id='" + data.id + "'] .votingFeedback").html(data);`

But you will also want to rename the parameter of the success function because you are defining `data` twice. This will mean that `data.id` doesn't exist anymore. Rename it to something like `response` or rename the parameter of the outer function.

Comment: I think I have a unique id applied to each of the voting elements, but don't know how to use it as a selector

Comment: lol That's the problem I don't know how to use that div id as a selector.

Comment: It's giving me a Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [data-id='undefined' .votingFeedback]

Comment: I updated the answer. You are using the same parameter name in your success callback which is redefining `data`. Remember to use different parameters names.

Comment: it's working but another error  Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [data-id='61' .votingFeedback]

Comment: The .votingFeedback class needs to be outside the brackets. Sorry about that